# What if a Mezuzah is mistakenly removed?

Tags: halacha, gentiles, mitzvah, mistakes, mezuzah

Say a non-Jewish tradesman, like a painter, is working on a door and removes the Mezuzah without really knowing what he's doing. Is the Mezuzah still kosher? Could I say a Bracha and put it back as soon as I can?

I'm not sure if this counts as bizuy mitzvah, because it was performed by a non-Jew without my knowledge.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. Do you think the Mezuza became unKosher because a non-Jew removed it? Are you asking about the Bracha?

Comment: I'm asking if the Mezuzah has become non-Kosher in the circumstance. If not, how should one restore it to its proper place?

Comment: Unless there is suspicion that the mezuzah (the actual parchment) was removed from the case and damaged, it remains kosher if it was kosher prior to removal. Despite popular notion, the mezuzah refers only to the parchment, even though ma y people incorrectly assume the case is the mezuzah.  The

Comment: Parchment contains scripture written to exacting terms by a scribe. It is suggested that the mezuzah be checked for from time to time for errors or wear and tare from time and elements. . Given the circumstances, now may be a good time to have it checked by a scribe. Just remember , if deemed unkosher, it is not likely due to being touched by a non-Jew. It probably was not kosher for some time. The mezuzah can be repaired and put back in place

Answer (score 1):

If a mezuza was taken down with the intent of putting it back *soon*, then there's a dispute if one needs to make another Bracha (and therefore one doesn't make another Bracha).

Having a non-Jewish worker manhandle the Mezuzah does not affect its validity.

If the Mezuza fell off, or was taken down with no intent of returning it soon - as in your case - then it has to be put back up with a Bracha.

So says the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch in [סימן יא - הלכות מזוזה](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00561.html#HtmpReportNum0010_L2)

> אִם נָפְלָה הַמְּזוּזָה מֵעַצְמָה וְחוֹזֵר וְקוֹבְעָהּ, צָרִיךְ גַּם כֵּן לְבָרֵךְ, אֲבָל אִם הוּא הֵסִירָהּ כְּדֵי לְבָדְקָהּ, יֵשׁ לְהִסְתַפֵּק אִם צָרִיךְ לְבָרֵךְ... ‏
>
> וְיֵשׁ לְקָבְעָהּ בְּלֹא בְרָכָה, אוֹ שֶׁיִּקְבְּעֶהָ לְאַחַר שֶׁיִּקְבַּע בְּפֶתַח הַמְּחֻיָּב, וִיבָרֵךְ וְיִפְטֹר גַּם אֶת זֹאת וְכֵן בְּכָל מָקוֹם שֶׁיֵּשׁ סָפֵק, יַעֲשֶׂה כֵּן‏

As a general rule, one should remove the Mezuzah if the doorpost is being painted or otherwise worked on. This prevents paint (and other substances) from leaking onto the writing and disqualifying it.

If a door**post** was removed, and then returned, then the Mezuzah has to be removed and put back again with a Bracha. Even if just the door was removed there could be an issue, so it's best to remove the Mezuzah before renovating doors.

> יֵשׁ אוֹמְרִים דַּאֲפִלּוּ אֵין דְּלָתוֹת לַפֶּתַח, חַיָּב בִּמְזוּזָה. וְיֵשׁ אוֹמְרִים דְּבָעֵינָן דַּוְקָא דֶלֶת. וְלָכֵן לֹא יִקְבַּע אֶת הַמְּזוּזָה עַד שֶׁיִּתְלֶה מִקֹּדֶם אֶת הַדֶּלֶת. וְלֹא יִקְבַּע אוֹתָהּ תְּחִלָּה וְאַחַר כָּךְ יִתְלֶה אֶת הַדֶּלֶת, מִשּׁוּם דְּבָעֵינָן תַּעֲשֶׂה וְלֹא מִן הֶעָשׂוּי ‏