# How long without a mezuza when painting a house?

Tags: halacha, mezuzah

Assume that you are painting your house, that you live in, and that will involve taking down all the mezuzot.  Assume the painting will take 2 weeks, to paint all the rooms.  Assume that painting any one room (and doorway) will take 2 days (for prep and priming and then paining two coats), so any one room/doorway will have no mezuza for at least one overnight and perhaps as much as 2-3 days.  How long may a house or room be without a mezuza and you still be allowed to live in it?  It is necessary to put up a mezuzza as soon as each coat of plaster or paint is dry, or can replacing the mezuzot be done when all the painting is completed?
 Related: [Source that every room in the house needs a mezuza](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/96185/source-that-every-room-in-the-house-needs-a-mezuza)

Comment: I'm confused why they'd be taken down at all?

Comment: @DoubleAA https://www.yeshiva.co/ask/2398

Comment: slightly related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/65190/what-if-a-mezuzah-is-mistakenly-removed

Comment: @loewian how would they get damaged? Do discolored cases warrant taking down the scrolls??

Comment: What does one room have to do with another? In other words, why would the front door or kitchen door not have a mezuza when painting a bedroom?

Comment: @Mordechai  It depends on the approach of the painter. If the painter does all the surface prep and priming before painting, then the whole house would be without a mezuza for 2 weeks.  If the painter goes room by room, then any given room might be without a mezuza for 2 days.